# ASP.NET Web API Route not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have just added a new Web API controller to my project. Now, I am trying to invoke the controller from JavaScript. But first I am also interested to manually invoke the route which is not pulling up anything. It says "Page Not Found".

My RegisterRoutes methods is shown below:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                url: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

My API controller is called FlightsController:

```
 public class FlightsController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<FlightViewModel> GetAllFlights()
        {
            return new List<FlightViewModel>() { new FlightViewModel() { Name = "Some Flight" }};
        }
}
```

I am trying to access it using the following URL:

```
http://localhost:54907/api/flights // The resource not found
http://localhost:54907/MyProject/api/flights // resource not found 
api/flights // name not resolved
```

What am I doing wrong?

**VERSION: I added a new file to my controllers directory which is called "Web API Controller Class (v2.1)**

UPDATE: Here is my updated web.config

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.RegisterRoutes);

            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        }
```

Comment: Tell us which version of the WebApi/MVC framework you are using so we can help you better. WebApi has gone through many changes that can have an impact on this problem.

Comment: Web API Controller (v2.1) , .NET 4.5, ASP.NET MVC runtime version 4.0

Comment: Where do you call `RegisterRoutes(..)` from?

Comment: RegisterRoutes is called from inside the Global.asax file. This is the default implementation and I have not changed it.

Comment: Are you trying to access the controller or action?

Comment: @Nipuna If I call api/flights then it will automatically should pick up GetAllFlights action.

Comment: @johndoe As far as I know, unless the controller has a action named Index, with defaults you need to specify the action as well

Answer (score 15):

I was having the similar issues and I decided to download the example from [this website](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) and compare the difference. Eventually, I fixed my issue by switching the sequence of the route registering function calls in Global.asax.cs file.

Instead of :

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.RegisterRoutes);
```

Call the WebApiConfig.RegisterRoutes first, that is:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.RegisterRoutes);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

I'm still investigating the reasons behind. But hope this could help.

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was fixed by changing the order. Thx !

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using HttpAttributeRoutes

Decorate your controller

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/flights")]
    public class FlightsController : ApiController
    {
       [Route("")]
        public IEnumerable<FlightViewModel> GetAllFlights()
        {
            return new List<FlightViewModel>() { new FlightViewModel() { Name = "Some Flight" }};
        }
    }
```

Register your routes...

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        #region Public Methods and Operators       

        public static void RegisterRoutes(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a MVC Controller when you put the route in RouteConfig.cs. You should move the api route to App_Data/WebApiConfig.cs.

**RouteConfig:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**WebApiConfig:**

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

**Edit:**
It doesn't really matter where the action is located. As long as you call it from `Application_Start()` in Global.asax.cs you could just add something like

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure((config) => 
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
});
```

Comment: I cannot add any files to App_Data folder manually. And currently that folder is empty.

Comment: I am invoking using http://localhost:54907/MyProject/api/flights it still does not return anyting

Comment: take out MyProject while using IISExpress.

Comment: I did and still The resource cannot be found.

Comment: Wait! The RegisterRoutes on WebApiConfig is not getting called. Where should I call it

Comment: Try adding your own routes to the api controller as I've posted above.  It gives you greater flexibility beyond the standard GET POST PUT conventions.

Comment: Call it in the Global.asax.cs

Comment: How do I pass the RegisterRoutes method the argument which is HttpConfiguration

Comment: It doesn't really matter where it is located as long as you call it from Global.asax.cs, I'll update the answer

Comment: What do I pass into  WebApiConfig.RegisterRoutes( WHAT DO I PASS HERE  );

Comment: GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.RegisterRoutes)

Comment: Put that line in your Global.asax.cs

Comment: Still the same issue "The resource cannot be found".

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is on top of the answer @freddyloix gave, decorate your controller with the routing attributes as I posted above.

Comment: If you didn't, you also have to remove the api-route from RouteConfig or the application will crash when it starts.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But even with decorating with the attribute does not work. I will have to think of a different solution.

Answer (score -1):

Your API route does not have an action defined and the routing engine cannot get you there:

```
http://localhost:54907/api/flights // The resource not found
```

This route does not have an action defined or a default. The routing engine will take you to a controller but has not action (method) to map to.

```
http://localhost:54907/MyProject/api/flights // resource not found
```

Unless you mapped the application to "MyProjects" in IIS or similar you will run into the same problem as above.

Comment: How can I define what I am missing?

Comment: Change the routing `url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` and call `http://localhost:54907/api/flights` to see it function. Next you can change `GetAllFlights` to 'Flights' to keep with your desired api.

Comment: Same issue as I wrote in the original post. The page does not exist.